# Chef Cookbook Compilation Error While Bootstrapping The Node

Tags: encryption, chef-infra, bootstrapping, knife, databags

I am using chef to bootstrap a node. I have created encrypted data bags and copied the secret key on the node as /etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret.

When I try to bootstrap the node, I am getting the following error:

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/webapps-configs/recipes/httpd.rb
================================================================================
 Net::HTTPServerException
 ------------------------
 404 "Not Found"
 Cookbook Trace:
 ---------------
   /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/webapps-configs/recipes/httpd.rb:12:in `from_file'
 Relevant File Content:
 ----------------------
 /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/webapps-configs/recipes/httpd.rb:

  10:
  11:  CHEF_ENV = node.chef_environment
  12>> http_ssl_creds = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("#{CHEF_ENV}", "http-ssl")
  13:  PRIVATE_KEY = http_ssl_creds["private_key"]
  14:  CHAIN_FILE= http_ssl_creds["chain_file"]
  15:  CERT= http_ssl_creds["cert"]
  16:

 ERROR: Running exception handlers
 FATAL: Saving node information to /var/chef/cache/failed-run-data.json
 ERROR: Exception handlers complete
 Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
 FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
 FATAL: Net::HTTPServerException: 404 "Not Found"
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Net::HTTPServerException: 404 "Not Found"
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2632:in `error!'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/rest.rb:199:in `block in raw_http_request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/rest.rb:280:in `retriable_rest_request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/rest.rb:164:in `raw_http_request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/rest.rb:158:in `api_request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/rest.rb:99:in `get'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/data_bag_item.rb:149:in `load'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/encrypted_data_bag_item.rb:294:in `load'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/webapps-configs/recipes/httpd.rb:12:in `from_file'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:30:in `instance_eval'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:30:in `from_file'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:346:in `load_recipe'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/run_context.rb:151:in `load_recipe'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:139:in `block in compile_recipes'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:137:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:137:in `compile_recipes'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:74:in `compile'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/run_context.rb:86:in `load'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/client.rb:224:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/client.rb:467:in `do_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/client.rb:200:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/application.rb:190:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/application/client.rb:297:in `block in run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/application/client.rb:290:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/application/client.rb:290:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/application.rb:73:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'
```

Any help or pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. It appears that the environment was not created properly. So when I was bootstrapping the node, its environment was being set to "_default", hence the node was unable to locate the items.

I recreated the environment, and bootstrapped node by passing --environment parameter, and I was able to bootstrap without any issues.

Once again, thanks to all the contributors for their inputs. This community is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following line to your recipe:

```
  11. CHEF_ENV = node.chef_environment
+ 12. Chef::Config[:encrypted_data_bag_secret]
  13. http_ssl_creds = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("#{CHEF_ENV}", "http-ssl")
  14. PRIVATE_KEY = http_ssl_creds['private_key']
  15. CHAIN_FILE= http_ssl_creds['chain_file']
  16. CERT= http_ssl_creds['cert']
```

Another thing to check is that the node environment is the name of your encrypted data bag.

since you 've copied the **/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret** to the node, that should do the trick.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. My recipe already contains the above mentioned code. I resolved my issue, it appears that the environment was not being created properly, and environment for node was set to "_default" when bootstrapped. I recreated the environment and bootstrapped with --environment flag, and the error was resolved. Thanks again for taking time to answer this :). Much Appreciated!!

Comment: I upvoted the answer because it points to the exact falling point, and might help someone to narrow down similar issues.